# Finding files in sub directories

Tags: find, ls

Still a newbie.  Using a clean machine, purchased from System 76 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.  Got it mid-May of 2014.

Why can't I find files in the current and its subdirectories?

I've tried `ls`, `find` , `locate`, `which`, and `whereis`.  Even `tree | grep` which will find them but won't tell me *where* they are.

**Example:** In my `/home` directory I have some `*.t` files.  In some of my directories below home, I have some *.t files.  I am having a hard time trying to find them all with one CLI command.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is `find . -type f -name "*.t"` not giving the expected output?

Comment: Can you add the actual commands you used and also show a list of a location where those files are with the given search argument! I'll expand the answer if needed ;)

Comment: `which` is used to see the absolute path to a program's executable. like `which firefox` or `which bash`

Comment: Thank you g_p.  I hadn't realized I needed 'find' with 'type' and 'name'.  This does the trick.  Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you LittleByBlue.  I see I still have a lot to learn.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `locate` might be an outdated database. locate uses a database to show you result and that database is not updated real-time. So new files are not added to it when created. They will get added when the database is updated.

```
sudo updatedb
```

updates it for you manually but this is also done daily by cron on a default Ubuntu. locate is not real-time but very fast. locate accepts wildcards.

```
locate *.jpg 
/discworld/Downloads/Forbidden-Oasis.jpg
/discworld/Downloads/The-Exalted-Plains.jpg
/discworld/Downloads/The-Fallow-Mire.jpg
/discworld/Downloads/The-Hinterlands.jpg
/discworld/Downloads/The-Storm-Coast.jpg
/discworld/Downloads/The-Western-Approach.jpg
```

and

```
locate .t
```

should give you results if the database is up to date and there are any files ending with ".t". You can filter the results by adding a `| grep Western` (the example I show above would show 1 result; the last one would be shown) if you get too many results.

---

`find` is real-time and as a result it is slower than `locate`. `find` will show an error if you search location you are not allowed to search. The command in comments by @g_p is correct and searches from the current location files ending in ".t".

```
find . -type f -name "*.t"
```

---

`which` is not intended to find files but to find commands so is the wrong tool. `whereis` is also not intended to find files but you can use to find the binary, source, and manual page files for a command.

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind!  Locate *.t gives me way too many results of all sorts.  Locate "*.t" gives me exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much Rinzwind!

Comment: @ReyKev you can filter with "| grep {filter}" ;)

Comment: Thank you again Rinzwind.  I will work with that.  Appreciated!